# Microsoft USB Mouse speed very slow after waking PC

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

Waking computer from power saving or rebooting the PC results in the mouse cursor **moving extremely slowly**. The only way to fix it is to unplug and plug in the mouse.

I found this issue impossible to search for due to all the false positives about Synaptic drivers. I have no touchpad, this is a desktop tower.

Specs:

- Desktop PC
- Windows 10
- Microsoft USB Wheel Mouse Optical
- Asus X399-A mainboard
- Many USB 2/3 sockets.
- USB keyboard

[image: Device Manager]

**Edit: I noticed that it isn't just moving *slowly*, it is more like *it doesn't notice any input most of the time.* Like most of the messages from mouse are being discarded. I'm thinking like an interrupt issue.**

Comment: Is the USB mouse plugged into a USB hub of some sort?

Comment: USB is plugged into X399-A Asus mainboard. I've tried all of the usb sockets.

Comment: (1) Try in *Settings > Devices > Mouse > Additional mouse options > Pointer Options* and disable "Enhance Pointer Precision". (2) Does this happen after booting in Safe mode? (3) Does this happen with the same mouse on another computer? (4) Try in Device Manage to delete the device then reboot using the keyboard (or unplug and replug may work) (5) Try to [disable the USB selective suspend](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-selective-suspend-enable-disable).

Comment: @harrymc Why not put this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: As you wish - might be easier to read this way.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:

1. Try in *Settings > Devices > Mouse > Additional mouse options > Pointer Options*
   to disable "Enhance Pointer Precision".
2. Does this happen after booting in Safe mode?
3. Does this happen with the same mouse on another computer?
4. Try in Device Manage to delete the device then reboot using the keyboard
   (or just unplug and replug may work)
5. Try to
   [disable USB selective suspend](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-selective-suspend-enable-disable).

Comment: 1) Point precision doesn't help.
3) Yes on a similar setup. win10 older asus mb.

Comment: The other questions may help pinpoint the problem. In addition: 6. Does this happen with another mouse on same computer?

Comment: Looks like I have some stuff to try. I had this problem in the past but i don't recall which machine and which os, and mouse.